# Who has the highest effective health?

Tags: warframe

With Valkyr prime [soft confirmed recently](http://images.akamai.steamusercontent.com/ugc/273986176740647045/8EA3C3150396659379A06DDC3A8A41D163FA6785/), it got me thinking, who has the highest amount of [effective health](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Health#Effective_Health) ([health](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Health) as it is affected by [armor](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Armor)) including a maxed [Steel Fiber](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Steel_Fiber) and [Armored Agility](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Armored_Agility), and whatever mods for boosting health (ex. [Vitality](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Vitality), [Vigor](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Vigor), [Physique](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Physique), etc.)? I ask this particularly between [Inaros](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Inaros) and [Valkyr](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Valkyr), because although Valkyr has higher armor, Inaros has *much* higher health. Also how do their respective abilities ([Warcry](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Warcry) and [Scarab Swarm](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Scarab_Swarm)) affect this?

Also, where would [Valkyr Prime](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Valkyr/Prime)'s 700 base armor and 300 base health put her?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effective Health is a variable, making it hard to say one Warframe has a higher effective health than another, as it is affected by many other variables including the types of enemies you encounter.
From the page you link under "[Effective Health:](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Health#Effective_Health)"

> Effective health can only ever be considered in the context of damage, because its value depends on the bonuses and penalties of the incoming damage as much as it does on the resistance values of your armor, mods, and health.
>   Depending on how you build your Warframe and use its abilities, you can experience a drastic difference in survival between different types of enemies.
>   (A specific build of Valkyr has been shown to have ~3800 effective health against most Grineer but only ~850 effective health against typical Corpus enemies.)

We can figure out who has a higher effective health in a standard way quite easy, the formula is:

Effective Health = Health / (1 - Damage Reduction)

The Damage Reduction comes from your armour, which has the formula:

Damage Reduction = Armour / (300 + Armour)

Using these formulas, we can get quick values for both frames as follows:

Rank 30 Inaros:  (+ Steel Fiber and Armored Agility)
Health: 2,200
Armour: 510
Damage Reduction = 0.6296
Effective Health = 5939.52

Rank 30 Valkyr:  (+ Steel Fiber and Armored Agility)
Health: 300
Armour: 1530
Damage Reduction = 0.8361
Effective Health = 1830.38

Rank 30 Valkyr Prime: (+ Steel Fiber and Armored Agility)
Health: 300
Armour: 1785
Damage Reduction = 0.8561
Effective Health =  2084.78

**From the above we can see that Inaros has the highest base effective health,

however I'd like to restate that this is only for a base damage calculation and does not include the many other modifiers such as damage type (toxic, fire, etc) that can make the armour, and thus the Damage Reduction, more or less effective.**